# Cassandra read Column

Tags: cassandra-2.0

`String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM local";
for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement)) {
  System.out.println(row.toString());
}`

how to get each Column value from the selected row ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using cassandra ds-driver the following should work for you.

```
String cqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM local"; 
for (Row row : session.execute(cqlStatement))
        {
            row.getString("columnName"); // for string data type
//            row.getBool("columnName"); for boolean data type
//            row.getUUID("columnName"); for UUID type
//            row.getVarint("columnName"); for int type
//            row.getLong("columnName"); for long type
//            row.getDate("columnName"); for date type
//            row.getBytes("columnName"); for bytes/anonymous type
        }
```